# How to maintain order of HTML head / body blocks getting loaded in to meteor application?

Tags: javascript, meteor

From http://docs.meteor.com

> Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level
>   elements: <head>, <body>, and <template>. The head and body sections
>   are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are
>   transmitted to the client on initial page load.

Really good feature, but I got following problem now.

How to maintain order of HTML head / body blocks getting loaded in to meteor application?

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing is most likely something like:

**file1.html**

```
<body>
    <!-- some stuff -->
</body>
```

**file2.html**

```
<body>
    <!-- some other stuff -->
</body>
```

---

Consider to use templates instead, so you can do something like this:

**main.html**

```
<body>
    {{> template1}}
    {{> template2}}
</body>
```

**file1.html**

```
<template name="template1">
    <!-- some stuff -->
</template>
```

**file2.html**

```
<template name="template2">
    <!-- some other stuff -->
</template>
```

---

**What you should be doing:** Making sure your templates help you define the HTML flow; everything else can be done with [CSS positioning](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/), even [changing flow for things with a defined height or width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92239/can-css-truly-override-the-order-of-html-elements-on-a-page).

**What you shouldn't be doing:** Alphabetically naming the files, such that Meteor takes them in order. Resorting the contents of the body using jQuery, use `.bind` or `.on` and listed for the event that DOM nodes get inserted; when one gets inserted, you shift it to the right place. *These are **bad habits***.

Comment: Thanks Tom,
I understand this. This is a solution to this problem.
But there are lot of HTML which doesn't meant to be on templates. like footer, header or something else. 
I will wait for a while before marking this answer as correct answer, if there is some specs for it in Meteor, I would like to know that.