# Float a div in top right corner without overlapping sibling header

Tags: css, html

Having a `div` and a `h1` inside a section, how do i float the div in the top right corner without overlapping the text of the header ?

The HTML code is the following:

```
<section>
  <h1>some long long long long header, a whole line, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6</h1>
  <div><button>button</button></div>
</section>
```

- I tried an absolute position relative to the parent but the text is overlapped, http://jsfiddle.net/FnpS8/2/

  [image: div overlapping text]

Using this CSS code:

```
section { position: relative; }
h1  { display: inline; }
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

- I tried floating the div to the right but it doesn't remain in the top right corner, http://jsfiddle.net/P6xCw/2/

  [image: div floated to the right]

Using this CSS code:

```
h1  { display: inline; }
div { float: right;    }
```

​

I know there is a lot of similar questions but I couldn't find one solving this case.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, sorry that I failed to post my answer simultaneously (jsfiddle link only not allowed). I also posted the wrong jsfiddle link for my first example so that 2 of you (@salih0vicX & @Juanjo) got it right only with CSS when in fact the right solution was to reorder the HTML elements (cf. @j08691 answer & mine). Sorry for that.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you can change the order of the elements, floating will work.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
h1 {
  display: inline;
}
div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>

  <h1>some long long long long header, a whole line, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6</h1>
</section>
```

​By placing the `div` **before** the `h1` and floating it to the `right`, you get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer while writing the question, but SO didn't let me post them together. Appears we can't just post the jsfiddle link ^^ Congrats for the blazing fast answer :)

Comment: @MaximeR. - thanks, but I was looking for the person who downvoted me to explain their downvote (once you reach a certain rep you can see the up/down vote breakdown).

Comment: @OZ_ - updated fiddle. I'm wondering now if that fiddle ever worked.

Answer (score 13):

Another [problem solved by the rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html):

The css is right but you still have to remember that the HTML [elements order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92278/343834): the div has to come before the header. http://jsfiddle.net/Fq2Na/1/
[image]

Change your HTML code to have the div before the header:

```
<section>
<div><button>button</button></div>
<h1>some long long long long header, a whole line, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6</h1>
</section>
```

And keep your CSS to the simple `div { float: right; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid from your  `<Button>`  wrap div using `display:block` and `float:left` in both `<Button>` and `<h1>` and specifying their `width` with a `position:relative` to your `Section`. This approach has the advantage of not needing another `div` only to position your `<Button>`

**html**

```
<section>  
    <h1>some long long long long header, a whole line, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6</h1>     
    <button>button</button>
</section>
```

​
**css**

```
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    float:left;
}
h1 {
    display: block;
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}
button
{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float:left;
}
```

​

Comment: But then I have two columns and lose the space beneath the button. Morevover, if the window is too small, the button will jump under header.

Comment: That's the behaviour expected from the `display:block` indeed. I just tried to show another way since everyone answered almost the same thing

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

It's similar to the approach of the media object, by Stubbornella.

Edit: As they comment below, you need to place the element that's going to float before the element that's going to wrap (the one in your first fiddle)